# Get Image URL for store into Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I have download image url - http://localhost:34676/v3/attachments/h2lk9kf5bgn6/views/original.
When I use this url in browser then image will be download instead of view in browser.
Now, I want to store this image into database then How can I do this?
Help me please.

**Update 2**

> {"name"=>"nodebot_error.png", "contentType"=>"image/png",
>   "contentUrl"=>"http://localhost:34676/v3/attachments/h2lk9kf5bgn6/views/original"}

above hash that I'm getting in the backend system. This response come from the Bot Microsoft Framework.

Comment: Could you show us some code. Your controller for example.

Comment: to view the image in the browser you'll need an `image_tag` view helper:
`<%= image_tag ' http://localhost:34676/v3/attachments/h2lk9kf5bgn6/views/original' %>` However I don't see the file extension. What file type is downloaded when you hit that endpoint?

Comment: I want to store into database. when I open that url in browser then It's download image.

Comment: Well you'd need to capture the specific url and then in your controller action you can do whatever you want with the parameter (ie: save it to a db)